# Is there any way to return Livewire component direct from the controller method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I was trying to return a livewire component from the controller. Something like the code below

```php
public function index(){
  return livewire(LivewireComponent:class, [
    'someParam' => $param;
  ]);
}
```

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you should probably use the full-page component routing, allowing you to forgo the needless controller function.

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#page-components

```
Route::get('/foo', LivewireComponent::class);
```

Comment: Thank you @ceejayoz
I know this option. But when I am using a resource route, I want to return the component from the controller. I don't want to define extra routes to override the resource route to use full-page component. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no. Livewire would tend to *replace* the functionality of a resource controller.